# Как предпочтительнее инициализировать массивы в конструкторе

Tags: c#, code-style

Вопрос стилистического плана, который уже несколько лет не дает мне покоя.
Какой вариант инициализации массива в конструкторе предпочтительнее (и почему):

**Вариант 1** через аргумент конструктора

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private double[] _array;

    public SomeClass(int arraySize)
    {
        ArraySize = arraySize;

        _array = new double[arraySize];
    }

    public int ArraySize { get; }
}
```

**Вариант 2** через свойство, предварительно проинициализированное аргументом конструктора

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private double[] _array;

    public SomeClass(int arraySize)
    {
        ArraySize = arraySize;

        _array = new double[ArraySize];
    }

    public int ArraySize { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

"несколько лет не дает мне покоя" - успокойтесь и не переживайте, никакой разницы нет, если только в сетере свойства нет логики, в результате которой эти два значения могут отличаться.

Comment: Для древней версии моно, которая ещё недавно юзалась в Unity - это тоже справедливо?

Comment: @Suvitruf Это справедливо для чего угодно.

Comment: Просто я видел случаи, когда геттеры/сеттеры замедляли работу после сборки в IL2CPP.

Comment: @Suvitruf Автор делает в вопросе упор на "стиль". Однако, если говорить о скорости, то вызов гетера должен быть пренебрежим по сравнению с распределением памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Через переменную конструктора.
На данный момент, практически никакой разницы нет, но в будущем логика работы геттера может измениться и, помимо возвращаемого значения, могут выполняться дополнительные действия.